# Can one add custom properties to NTFS folders?

Tags: filesystems, metadata, directory, ntfs

I would like to be able to add my own custom data/properties to existing folders on NTFS, so that if a folder is moved, the properties move with it. One solution would be to store a file within the folder to contain whatever I need or want.

What I am particularly interested in, is whether or not there is a way to add custom properties to the directory file system object itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235150/dsofile-c-api-ntfs-custom-file-properties

Answer (score 3):

If you are feeling brave (<del>or foolish</del>) perhaps an [Alternative Data Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) would be an alternative.

I am not sure if can be applied to a directory as opposed to a normal file and it's littered with concerns that need to be considered:

1. There are no standard windows user tool that lists them (e.g. can't view from explorer or cmd prompt, but *can* be opened in most programs given correct name).
2. They will not transfer off of the NTFS filesystem well.
3. They may also raise some AV flags, I do not know.

Happy coding.

Comment: Nothing foolish about alternate data streams, they're designed for this kind of thing. And, yes, they do work on directories.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way in c# to show file custom properties

```cs
DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass file = new DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass();

file.Open(@"C:\setup.exe", false, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);

string key = "key1";

object value = "value1";

// Adds new custom property.

file.CustomProperties.Add(key, ref value);

// Go through existing custom properties.

foreach (DSOFile.CustomProperty p in file.CustomProperties)

{
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", p.Name, p.get_Value().ToString());
}

file.Close(true);
```

First in file.CustomProperties.Add(key, ref value);
 by modifying the attribute key(the property, you can modify it, here are the following.
in key you should put one of the following attribute_names, that are here described as constants by names from their real values

```
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 1
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 2
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = 4
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = &H10
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = &H20
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED = &H40
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = &H80
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = &H100
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE = &H200
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = &H400
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED = &H800
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE = &H1000
Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = &H2000
```

Then you should assign the desired value to the constant, in value

Then to see each properties of each file it show them on the line

```cs
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", p.Name, p.get_Value().ToString());
```