# Creating a custom file property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one add custom properties to NTFS folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179784/can-one-add-custom-properties-to-ntfs-folders)

I am trying to write a standalone executable in C# that attaches a value to a text file (without changing the content of the file) which can be read later.

I have looked into the following solutions but none of them quite work:

- **Shell32.dll**: Only appears to allow reading the properties.  I could not find any information on how to use Shell32 to write properties.
- **DSOFile**: App needs to be standalone and I am also concerned about future OS compatibility.
- **NTFS Alternate Data Streams (ADS)**: Many tools will not copy this information if the file is moved or copied and I am concerned about future compatibility.

Is there another way (COM, Etc..) to attach a custom property to a text file in .NET?

Comment: When you say "custom properties" do you mean the kind that appear on the details tab of a file's Properties dialog? If so I believe what you need to create is a shell metadata handler, although I'm not certain. MSDN has more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761474(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I should also add that shell property handlers are in-proc COM servers which run inside the shell (explorer). Having a shell extension which depends on the .NET Runtime is a bad idea because it causes the CLR to be injected into the shell, as well as processes which use shell APIs that require extensions to be loaded. Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply's:

The possible duplicate question discusses ADS which has already been considered.

Comment: The information does not need to be visible in the file properties dialog and as you mentioned using .NET to create a shell extension isn’t necessarily advisable.  I just need a value (10-20 char) to be attached to the file somehow so that it can be retrieved later.  

Using Zip file to bundle the two together will not work based on application constraints.

Comment: I think, that the answer to you question is no. The how files are stored is governed by a particular file system that you are using, and if this file system not allowing you to attach metadata to a file, you can't attach metadata to a file. You can work around storing this information elsewhere and linking it to the file but other means.

Comment: Shell32 and DSO are related to *specific kind of files*. In case of them the information is stored rather in the file itself (i.e. in the content of the file, such as an ms office document metadata) or in predefined "fields" on the file system (such as creation date, etc). If you only processing a particular file types, maybe you can find a place to store this information somewhere *inside* the file?

Answer (score 3):

The only three ways I can think of:

1. ADS - however you've already dismissed this.
2. Add it to the file name.
3. Add it to the beginning or end of the file.

If it's an application controlled file that may be moved around then your best bet is number two.  Of course, this means that the file may "lose" that info in a renaming operation.

The third option is a bit iffy.  If you can control how the file is viewed, then you can simply give it a different extension and write your data to the top of it.  When it needs to be opened you can "extract" the real file and open accordingly.  I think this is WAY more complicated... but it will contain your data and be less likely to be jacked with.