# "Attaching" files to one another in file system in windows (C# app - Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, ntfs

I am working on an app that adds data about a file (essentially the users input metadata about the files).  The method I had considered was something like

Mainfile.abc

Mainfile.abc.meta

where "Mainfile.abc.meta" would be a hidden file used by my app when necessary.  The problem is that users are going to be moving "Mainfile.abc" around and I want the ".meta" file to follow but only if it stays on the main server. (in other words, if the user copies "Mainfile.abc" to another drive the ".meta" file doesn't go with it.

For forensic reasons, I can't add/edit information in the main file itself.  It must remain exactly as it was.

I am trying to avoid having to re-create all the file system functions of adding/copying/moving/renaming/etc to my app when that is all built into Windows anyway.

For example, when saving a webpage as "webpage complete" Windows creates a separate directory of all the files associated with that webpage.  Simply copying the webpage automatically moves the webpage's files' folder along with it.  I'd like to do something similar.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: NTFS has alternate data streams, which work almost exactly as you describe.  You can also use custom properties to do the same.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179784/can-one-add-custom-properties-to-ntfs-folders

Comment: Can you edit an ADS over a mapped network location?

Comment: Yes, you can access alternate data streams via SMB.

Comment: Go ahead and post as an answer and I can close this.  Thanks!  I ended up using code from CodeProject by Sean Murphy.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS has alternate data streams, which work almost exactly as you describe. You can also use custom properties to do the same. See [Can one add custom properties to NTFS folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179784/can-one-add-custom-properties-to-ntfs-folders)

Comment: I guess @rune711 forgot about you :-(